# Angular routing along with backend routing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, smarty

I have an application where I have nginx+PHP routing finding controller-method pairs based on URL chunks, and calling appropriate view file from that method.

Nginx allows only to access www folder where I keep index.php, and assets like css, js, images or fonts.

Now how do angular routing fits in?

I want to use it to:
- make my architecture cleaner
- move operations on data there, to config angular function
- have the possibility to quickly build single app page

Is this even possible? I mean, I have to pass a template path inside angular, and I can't do that because I can't directly access view files.

Also the layout-template design is built on backend templating engine.

How can I do this?

Comment: Angular routes are typically applied in the hash portion of the URL- so you can route to a particular page on the server site, load the web app from the server, and then that web app would parse the hash portion of the URL and load the appropriate angularjs view.

Comment: @MikelBitson most Angular apps disable hash routing if it's a single-page app.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Yeah, but in his case he'd need to keep the hash routing, no? Other options for him?

Comment: You need to narrow the scope of your question. You're asking several broad questions here.

Comment: @MikelBitson yes, and no. There are multiple correct answers.